# clientContext is always null in Provider Hosted App

Tags: provider-hosted-app, spcontext, mvc

I am following this article- http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/building-apps-for-sharepoint-with-mvc/ to learn building Provider Hosted Apps in SharePoint. I have one developer site collection (I am the administer of the same).

I followed exact steps in the article but somehow I am always getting `null` value in `var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPAppWeb()`

I tried giving full read write access to Site Collection as well as particular List I am trying to access. I know it doesn't have to do with the permissions of the application.

I get the context when I try `var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost()`but not with `var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPAppWeb()`

I am very new to SharePoint 2013 and Provider hosted apps. Hope someone will help me out..

Regards,
RP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have app web for that. In provider hosted app, app web is not present by default. Create an empty module or list in your app web; basically in SP project which gets created when you create a provider hosted app and then you will have context.

Besides that, why do you need context of app web of you don't have anything in there?